# Gradient estimation for solutions of elliptic equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I know that for harmonic function $0\leq u\in C^2(D)$, there holds
$$
\left| \nabla u\left( x_0 \right) \right|\le \frac{C}{r^{d+1}}\int_{B_r\left( x_0 \right)}{ u\left( x \right)}dx,\quad B_r\left( x_0 \right) \subset D .
$$

So I want to know that whether this estimation also holds for the solution of general elliptic equations such as
$$ Lu=D_j(a_{ij}D_iu)=0,$$
if so, what assumptions maybe need for $(a_{ij})$?

I know the estimation holds when $u$ is harmonic since $u$ satisfies mean value property, but when $u$ is a solution of $Lu=0$, what formula can be found to replace the mean-value-property.

Comment: Unless you are asking about _minimal_ assumptions on $a_{ij}$ for which this holds (this is a topic of somewhat current research), look up "Schauder estimates." It's not sufficient to assume that $a_{ij}$ is just elliptic, and Schauder theory proves this type of estimate if $a_{ij} \in C^{0,\alpha}$.